# What do I need to do to execute sample golang code having a 'named' import like below?

Tags: go

This is newbie question. The dependencies seems to be on github, and it's pretty obvious from the import, so why run doesn't work?

**Error is: no required module provides package github.com/hashicorp/go-getter**

```
    package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "os"
// Problem with line below, getting error: no required module provides package
    getter "github.com/hashicorp/go-getter"
)

func main() {
    client := &getter.Client{
        Ctx: context.Background(),
        //define the destination to where the directory will be stored. This will create the directory if it doesnt exist
        Dst: "/tmp/gogetter",
        Dir: true,
        //the repository with a subdirectory I would like to clone only
        Src:  "github.com/hashicorp/terraform/examples/cross-provider",
        Mode: getter.ClientModeDir,
        //define the type of detectors go getter should use, in this case only github is needed
        Detectors: []getter.Detector{
            &getter.GitHubDetector{},
        },
        //provide the getter needed to download the files
        Getters: map[string]getter.Getter{
            "git": &getter.GitGetter{},
        },
    }
    //download the files
    if err := client.Get(); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Error getting path %s: %v", client.Src, err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    //now you should check your temp directory for the files to see if they exist
}
```

Comment: what go version are you using. Maybe you are using go mod, in such case, follow on below answer to initialize the package and fetch its dependencies. That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Create a folder somewhere called `getter`, then create a file
`getter/getter.go`:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "github.com/hashicorp/go-getter/v2"
)

func main() {
   fmt.Println(getter.ErrUnauthorized)
}
```

Notice I didn't use a name like you specified, as it's redundant in this case. The package is already called `getter` [1], so you don't need to specify the same name. Then, run:

```
go mod init getter
go mod tidy
go build
```

1. https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/go-getter/v2